# Alexa Skill, Audio play back is taking time

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, alexa-skills-kit, audio-player

i'm working on Alexa skill with audio play list.The audios are placed on same S3 bucket and i'm using URL of that particular location (with cloud-front enabled).

The issue is that some audios take time to start (i.e. 5 seconds), whereas, some start quickly. There's no difference in file size or file location, and same code is being used for all the audios. Although, i guess it's some issue with **Alexa audio player**.

My code to play audio is as:

```
this.response.audioPlayerPlay('REPLACE_ALL', url, token, null, offset);
```

Please note, i'm working in node.js, my end point is a lambda function and i'm using 'alexa-sdk' (node package)

I'm unable to understand the issue. Please help.

Comment: Hi @Fayza , Even i'm working on Alexa audio skill, and being newer in this i am not able to find any suitable example for the same can you please provide me some working code example which is using Audio directive of Alexa, i'll appreciate your help.

Comment: @PardeepJain, this link helped me as starting point: https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player

Comment: Thanks for reference, but i already checked this, faced lot of errors while customization that's why asking for your code. anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the audio files, and everything is working like a charm now. I believe, it was audio's issue and not player's.